# How to pass query results to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to create list of countries using javascript function such as :

```
    <div id='content'>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {               
           var countries = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", ...);

            // Create a jqxComboBox
            $("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox({source: countries, multiSelect: true, width: 600, height: 25});           


            $("#arrow").jqxButton({  });
            $("#arrow").click(function () {
                $("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox({ showArrow: false });
            });
            .       
            .
            .
```

But I'd like to change the source of var countries to be taken from my database, my sql query is $q = "SELECT country FROM countrytbl";

I'm still beginner in js so have no idea about how to do that!!

Note: each country should be in two quotations "" in order to make the list works

Comment: What server language are you using to generate this page? Browser JavaScript can't usually interact directly with a database, so you need to have your server talk to the database, either before the page is rendered, or in a script designed to run after the fact (such that JavaScript asks your custom server script to get the data from MySQL).

Comment: I'm using mysql database with php pages including some js inside these pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this

```
var countries = <?php echo json_encode($countries); ?>;
```

Where `$countries` is your array of results.  For example if your PHP array is like this:

```
$countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania");
```

Then the end result of your HTML will be like this:

```
<div id='content'>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {               
           var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania"];
 ...
```

After PHP does it's thing.  Of course this assumes whatever file this HTML is in has access to the `$countries` variable (and it's properly populated and defined).  If it doesn't you'll get a javascript error for this:

```
var countries = ;
```

Which will probably be in the source code for your page.

Just FYI JSON, you may see it sometimes, stands for Javascript Object Notation.  Which is a fancy way of saying a way to represent Javascript Objects (and Arrays) as a string.  So `json_encode` transforms your PHP array into a string that Javascript can understand as an array (in this case).  Then like any string in PHP/HTML files you just echo it out where you want it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well, how to get database query like this $countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", ..);?

Comment: I tried to make query in a php part like this but the countries list still empty     <?php 
$q = "SELECT country FROM countrytbl"; 

foreach ($db->query($q) as $row){

$countries = $row["country"];
}

?>

Comment: @sandanet change one line to `$countries[] = $row["country"];` - this will add the country to the array $countries. EDIT: Ah, and the foreach is wrong. Search for `mysqli_fetch_array()`. See this example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881

Comment: wow finally it's done, as u mentioned i did changes like this $query=mysqli_query($db,$q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):
$countries[] = $row["country"];
endwhile;

Comment: yup sure, i did it